# How to begin animation when view is displayed?

Tags: ios, animation, uiimageview, cabasicanimation

When I launch my application and go to flipSideViewController from mainViewController the image view in flipSideViewController will animate. I want to animate it every time the user 
transitions from mainViewController to flipSideViewController.

Here's some code:

```
[self animate];
//Not sure where to put this instance method. Would I put this in a certain method? I have no idea what I would write for it!

- (void)animate 
{
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
    animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((-10*M_2_PI)/180)];
    animation.duration = .3;
    animation.autoreverses = YES;
    animation.repeatCount = 4;
    animation.speed = 9;
    pwAnimation.removedOnCompletion = YES;
    [_ImageView.layer addAnimation:pwAnimation forKey:@"rotation"];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ViewDidAppear delegate method of flipSideViewController to invoke your -animate method